# Callback in renderer function for ExtJS Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I've got a renderer function that has to load some data from a store in order to return a value, but I haven't been able to figure out how to return what I want to the grid column.

```
{header: 'Manager First Name', 
renderer: function(value, meta, record){
    record.Managers().load({
        scope: this,
        callback: function(managers, operation, success){
            if(success && managers){
               managers[0].getPerson({
                    scope: this,
                    callback: function(person, operation){
                        if(person){
                            return person.get("firstName");
                        } else {
                            console.error('This manager doesn\'t have a person record.');
                            return '';
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.error('No manager record for the shop '+record.getId());
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

I've tried placing `return` in front of the `load` and the `getPerson` functions to no avail. I thought of firing an event as well, but I'm not sure how that would look. Any ideas?

Comment: i have post an answer to a similar question. You can view this on the page [stackoverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11582271/193439)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would load your additional information prior to rendering the main grid. This way in the renderer() function you will use already loaded data.

Otherwise your renderer function will get called many times and you will have some big troubles loading your store asynchronously.

Comment: But then when I do async callbacks in the `beforerender` event, the renderer function ends up firing before my callbacks have gotten the data.

I know I can `return false` in the `beforerender` event in order to stop the rendering, but then how would I restart it? I don't see a `render` function and I think firing the `render` event wouldn't actually cause a render.

Comment: Well. Here is question for you. When you present your main grid, where and when do you load main data for it?