# extjs: how to use ajax call in column renderer?

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs3

What i've got now is this:

```
renderer : function(value) {
    var ret;
    var conn = new Ext.data.Connection();
    conn.request({
        method : 'POST',
        url : rsdBackend,
        params : {
            get_object_by_id : 'true',
            rsd_type : record.data.references_table,
            object_id : value,
            uid : logged_user_id
        },
        success : function(responseObject) {
            var data = Ext.decode(responseObject.responseText);
            ret = data[0].object_name;
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

If a column contains a link to another data (foreign key in database terms) i need to show the name of the object it references to.

So, the best approach i can think of is using ajax call in renderer. It works, but the problem is: how can i return response?

The above code won't work, cause `ret`is undefined where i'm trying to `return` it.

How can this be done, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will be able do this this way. Ajax call is asynchronous and `renderer()` function is synchronous. I can't imagine right now how you can mix it together.

You need to get all information required for `renderer()` functions (for all cells!) to complete before you render the grid. Why can't you create an additional store for it, load it before and then use it?

Comment: thanks, i know that a is for asynchronous=) i can't create store, cause i don't know what type of objects should i hold there. i either can't (m... don't want realy) create all possible stores, cause the number can be huge (no upper bound for that)

Comment: Then create an ActionColumn - add a button basically to a grid and then you can do whatever you want when user clicks that button.

Comment: Or you can simply create a link in the cell and subscribe to the render event of this link so you get your function called when link would be rendered - at that point you do your Ajax call and replace HREF element of this link with something else... This might actually work :) but you still will potentially have a situation when link is rendered but you don't have final destination for this link.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this thread [Sencha forum thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?72216-Grid-asynchronous-update-of-cell-data)

i have make an asynchronous renderer.

In my example i want to display the 'name' value of the first record in my record association.

"fileRecord_store()" is the name of my associative store ( create via "hasMany" association model )

In the grid panel you can make a renderer like this :

```
 { header: 'Filename',  dataIndex: 'Files_id',      flex: 2,
    renderer: function(value, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
          var divId = 'my_cell_to_update_' + record.id;
          record.columnsNameUpdate(divId);
          return String.format("<div id='" + divId + "'>Loading...</div>"); 
                }
},
```

and now in the model class i add this function :

```
columnsNameUpdate : function(divId){

    this.fileRecord_store().on('load', this.updateColumn,this, {divId : divId});
    this.fileRecord_store().load();
},

updateColumn : function(store, model, success, options){
    this.fileRecord_store().un('load', this.updateColumn,this);
    Ext.fly(options.divId).update(store.first().get('filename')); 
}
```

it's work fine for me !